# Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to use c3js for the chart with Lightning Component, but unluckily, I got an error with the external js file d3.v3.min.js.

[image: Error at importing phase]

import code:

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/c3js/c3-0.4.11/c3.min.css" 
              scripts="/resource/d3v3min, /resource/c3js/c3-0.4.11/c3.min.js" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterJsLoaded}" />
```

Could you guys tell me how to solve this issue for using c3js in Lightning Component. I really appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Ted, can you check in your org if your Locker Service is activated in "Critical Updates"? If yes, try deactivating it and try again. It might be because the external library is not compatible with Locker Service.

Comment: Hi @SE_User, thank you very much! solved it. Your answer help me solve the other issue with chartjs too. That's really awesome.

Comment: @ted hold on a sec - for D3 there was an issue in that library itself that made it's module initialization not function correctly with strict mode (made the assumption in 1 location that this === window). That has been fixed in the latest version of D3 which is 4.2.6 and works find with LS activated. Can you try updating your component to use D3 v4 and see if that fixes the issue in C3 (I suspect it will). The issues with chartjs are Locker's though and should all be corrected with the upcoming patch deploying to WInter'17 orgs sometime on or near 10/18

Comment: Hi @DougChasman, thank you very much for your caution. But my question was about using c3js,

Comment: @ted I just tried the combination of D3 v4 and C3 v0.4.11 and a different issue pops up - SVGPathElement is not exposed in the current version of Locker on production - this one is also fixed with the upcoming 10/18 patch.

Comment: @ted D3 and C3 work together and the issue you outlined above was in D3 code not C3 (the browser had not even gotten to C3 yet).

Comment: @DougChasman, you're right, C3 work with D3, and  the browser had not come to C3 yet, but when I deactivate the LS, it's worked. I mean the chart display on my test app. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ean8crzMiGQ2JFUlVfMW4yQ1E/view?usp=sharing 

There's another issue, maybe relate to this LS, like it's work on my test app, but not in lightning experience. I've created a lightning component tab, and it's only display the legend..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ean8crzMiGeHAteGtTX2VkUk0/view?usp=sharing 
(Sorry, I should post this as the new questions, shouldn't I? )

Comment: I just tried D3 v4 combined with C3 and C3 is not compatible with D3 v4 yet https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1648 (refers to d3.scale which does not exist anymore in D3 v4) - sigh. The problem with D3 v3 is its use of var d3_document = this.document in its initialization. In strict mode this === undefined inside of a "free" function. The trivial change to get D3 v3 to work is to change the very last line from }.(); to }.call(this);

Comment: Hi @DougChasman,  I have updated last line of D3 v3 as you recommended, and D3 v3 has passed, then browser comes to check C3 v3 and the issue happened with this c3.js file.
Message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined throws at /resource/c3js/c3.js:7695:24", follow this message I get this SVGPathElement is an undefined object.

Comment: @DougChasman, I really appreciate your help and valued answers.

Comment: @ted yes the SVGPathElement issue is the same one I mentioned I ran into a few comments earlier and the fix for that is already included in the patch to Winter'17 scheduled to deploy on or near 10/18